# Is the age to buy alcohol in the duty-free in an airport the same as the country?

Tags: airports, alcohol, malta

I'm flying back to the UK from Malta this weekend, and in Malta the drinking age to buy alcohol is 17 (which is how old I am.) Would I be able to buy alcohol from the Maltese airport?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111941/discussion-on-question-by-renumi-is-the-age-to-buy-alcohol-in-the-duty-free-in-a).

Answer (score 36):

The laws on alcohol purchase in an airport are set by the country the airport is in, and are almost always the same as purchasing outside the airport. I haven't researched the specific case of Malta, but I would expect you would be OK.

Note that countries also have laws about how old you need to be to import alcohol. In your case you will be OK, as the minimum age for a duty-free alcohol allowance coming to the UK is 17.

Comment: Although until the end of the year this won't be duty-free, just an intra Eu import.

Comment: **To emphasize**: be aware of the alcohol consumption age of the country you're flying into. If the OP were discovered attempting to bring alcohol into the USA at age 17, at a minimum, he'd have it confiscated, and may well be charged with under-age possession (minimum possession/consumption age in the US is 21). Not a fun way to start a trip to the US, nor a good way to end an enjoyable vacation somewhere else.

Comment: Where you would find differences in laws on alcohol purchase in airports, it tends not to be an age limit but whether you can buy it at all due to religious practices. The UAE has duty free alcohol in airports, but in the country tourists can only get alcohol from some hotels and nightclubs which must be consumed on the premises.

Comment: @Crazymoomin Just as an aside, from July 2019 non-Muslim tourists can now buy alcohol in shops in Dubai. You do need to bring your passport and fill out a form.